# Rtcwake run script after waking up

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run script after executing and waking up from **rtcwake** command. Next commands are run procedurally but I want to have other part of script running only after fully execution command. How to achieve it avoiding hacks like `sleep`? Sometimes it takes a few seconds for typing password and when I do it in more than 10 seconds it runs already script after rtcwake.

```
sudo rtcwake -m mem -t $DESIRED &

sleep 10

echo "Hello again $USER!"
```

Comment: here are [two approaches which use systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152039/how-to-run-a-user-script-after-systemd-wakeup)

Comment: I don't want to run the script every time after wakeup. Only when I manually run my script.

Comment: create some specific file in first script (with sudo rtcwake) and delete it in companion script (which gets called by systemd). if file exists then it was your call - unlink the file and do some stuff. And when there is no file then do nothing.

Comment: Did you found any solutions?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu unfortunately not. I went with sleep hack.